# Concurrent Python Wikipedia Package Requests

Tags: python, api, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am making a python application which uses the python Wikipedia package to retrieve the body text of 3 different Wikipedia pages. However, I am noticing very slow performance when retrieving the articles one at a time. Is there a method that I can use to retrieve the body text of 3 Wikipedia pages in parallel?

Comment: There are several Python Wikipedia libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 'raw' page you can use any python scraping library such as [twisted](https://github.com/twisted/twisted)/[scrapy](https://scrapy.org).
But, if you are looking for the parsed wiki format you should use [pywikibot](https://github.com/wikimedia/pywikibot)/[mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) with multiprocess.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a general purpose multiprocessing library, you could use `binge` (`pip install binge`):

```
def worker(url):
    (...)
    return urlbody

urls = ['https://www....',
        'https://www....',
        ...
        'https://www....']

from binge import B
list_of_urlbodies = B(worker)(urls)
```

cf: [binge documentation](https://github.com/ceyzeriat/binge/)